# Is it faster iterating columnwise than linewise over an n-m-Array?

Tags: arrays, performance, opencv, iteration, labview

I'll have this LABVIEW-program, where I have to iterate over large arrays (not queues) and thus I'm interested to speed them up the best as possible.

I think I've heard for OpenCV, when reading an element, the page where this element is extracted from, contains the following column elements. That means if I'd iterate by the lines for every element I'd have to load again a new page, which obviously slows down the whole process.

Does this apply to LABVIEW programs too?

Thanks for the support and kind regards

Comment: Data locality definitely affects all software.  Whether columnwise or rowwise is faster depends on whether the data is arranged in column-major or row-major order, which is usually determined by the language.  I have no idea which order LABVIEW uses.

Comment: Isn't it about two registers storing row-skip jump-size, and column-skip jump size?  Assembler reads the op, then moves the memory pointer that many elements forward to read or write.  Some silicon has faster ways of doing one than the other.  https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/Introduction_to_x64_Assembly.pdf  Maybe one could perform tricks with quadword registers in integer or binary arrays and have "16" elements in register at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I benchmarked this. 
I have 100000x5 2D array. By iterating rows first it takes some 9ms from my i7 processor to complete. Iterating by columns first takes some 35ms to complete.

[image]

Comment: NxN array will not help you to understand which option is faster. 
LabVIEW reads rows first, so when you have fewer rows, it executes faster, because each time bigger for loop allocates dynamic memory for each column. If you have 100000x5 2D array it would 100000 times allocate memory for 1D array of 5 elements. When you have 5x100000 2D array it would allocate memory only 5 times, which makes this option much faster.

Comment: again your innerloop (the one that gets iterated a lot more) is the rows loop then, right?

Comment: >  because each time bigger for loop allocates 
> dynamic memory for each column
Um... no. There's no memory allocated when iterating a loop like this. I work on the compiler. We just have a pointer back into the main array with a starting point and a stride.

Comment: newbie question here.  Does the performance change if you put an in-place modify to modify the value?  You could randomly flip a bit in the value, to get better than a no-op in the interior of the loop.  How does the speed change for binary/boolean array, integer array, double array?  To speak to @Joe Friedrichsen, how does the above change for a parfor loop?

Comment: @srm so if you work on the compiler, what is your opinion then ? Innerloop by rows or by cols ?

Comment: In the black points LabVIEW allocates memory: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mgjiyzc1h5h3v5s/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @user3085931 -- rows first

Comment: @KhachikSahakyan You aren't reading the buffer allocations correctly. The buffer at the far right is to avoid stomping on the constant. Your entire left hand side gets constant folded away, so a copy has to be made to be returned from the function so that the caller doesn't stomp on the value of the constant. That's not a copy being made during *indexing* of the loops.

Comment: srm, please explain the reason why 100000x5 takes faster than 5x100000?

Answer (score 2):

LabVIEW is row-major. If you take a 2D array and wire it to the border of a For Loop for auto indexing, the 1D arrays that you get out are the rows. Wire that into a nested For Loop to process the individual elements.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to row-then-column iteration, there are two techniques you can apply to maximize your array processing:

1. [Pipelining](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvconcepts/pipeline_intro/) - which helps maximize core utilization for sequential tasks
2. [Parallel For loops](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9393/en/) - which provide data-parallelism

After that, there are other more complex designs like structured grids. There is an NI white paper that describes [multi-core programming in LabVIEW](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/6099/en/), including these and other approaches, in more detail.

Comment: my question goes way deeper

Comment: lol, ok. Just as you think I don't understand your question, you don't understand my response. These techniques have been used to [process 100s of MB of data per second](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/11972/en/): LabVIEW doesn't get any deeper.

Comment: maybe 'way' is a little bit too much. But it's more about computer tech. memory access. Here everyone is doing his own thing and I just need to know how labview did that. It's like  Ben Voigt said